# highlighting mobile number based on search term?

Tags: javascript, regex

can someone help me highlighting a mobile number to (1**23**) **4**56-7890 when the search term is 234 in javascript?

I had a phone number of this kind of format (123) 456-7890 and I need to highlight the phone number based on the search term so that it needs to look like this (1**23**) **4**56-7890 if the search term is `234`.

```
const phoneNumber = "(123) 456-7890";

phoneNumber.replace("123","<strong>123</strong>")
```

This was working fine for only straight 3 numbers and having an issue with the special characters

Comment: Please give us clear inputs and the expected picture of the output.

Comment: Are you saying that part of a string has the pattern `(xyy)zxx-xxxx`, where each `x`, each `y` and `z` represents any digit, you are given a string of three digits, `uuv`, where each `u` and each `v` represent any digit, and you wish to replace `yy` with `uu` and `z` with `v`?

Answer (score 0):

String replace might not be able to dynamically replace different search term. The following produce a string as you wanted

```js
const phone = "(123) 456-7823";
const search = "234".split(""); // change the search term to whatever 

// this format the search char to strong, 
let formatted = phone.split("").map( c => {

  let index = search.indexOf(c);
  if( index !== -1){
    search.splice(index, 1);
    return `<strong>${c}</strong>`
  } else return c;

}); // an array

// join formatted to become a string
console.log(formatted.join(''));

// display html
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = formatted.join('');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solution is working only for the phone number which doesn't have repeat characters.

Comment: repeat characters? I updated the phone which has two '2' and '3' and it works as well?

Comment: I mean like how can we highlight only the first instance of `234`